# Embed Python in Xcode project

Tags: python, ios, xcode

I have a Python library that i want to add to my iOS app. Now i have included the Python library to the project. Now i need to add the python-embedded framework to my Xcode project.

I have downloaded an example from Github and everything work except the fact that i don't have libpython.a included. Because this library does not exists. How can i create this lib?

```
https://github.com/video-dl/python-embedded
```

How can i create the pythonlib.a and add it to my existing Xcode project?